# Using list.count to search for multiple items in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, count

So let's say my code is as follows:

```
Numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]

Print(Numbers.count(1,2))
```

How could I get the output to return 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `count` method of the `list` object only takes 1 argument. The easiest to achieve what you are looking for is to use a simple addition:

```
Numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(Numbers.count(1) + Numbers.count(2))
# outputs 2
```

Comment: I'm ashamed this was accepted, other answers are way better than mine.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest approach, using [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
sum(map(Numbers.count, (1,2)))
```

Once the number of elements that you want to count increases, you will be better off using a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and add the counts from there:

```
 from collections import Counter
 c = Counter(Numbers)
 sum(c[x] for x in (1,2))
```

The main advantage of the latter method is that the `Counter` obtains all counts in a single iteration while repeated `list.count` calls repeatedly iterate the list.

Answer (score 4):

Using `list.count` repeatedly will have complexity O(m*n). This isn't recommended. You can achieve your task with complexity O(m+n) by using `collections.Counter`:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4]

from collections import Counter

c = Counter(L)

res = sum(map(c.get, [1, 2]))  # 2
```

To cater for potential missing values, you can use `dict.__getitem__`:

```
res = sum(map(c.__getitem__, [1, 2]))
```

Comment: If you just use `c[i]` you won't even need the default value, as `Counter.__getitem__` will return `0` by default.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, Nice point, thank you! I do feel, though, stylistically, `__` methods aren't *meant* for front-end use. But you're right this is more efficient.

Comment: I agree. Particularly when the the generator expressions are so short and pretty. I also find it an odd design decision in `Counter` that `get` and `__getitem__` return different things for unknown keys.